# autolayout only on part of the storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

Is it possible to do auto layout only on part of the storyboard (a specific ViewController) -
I have a huge project with no autolayout and no time to fix it all (probably will never have time - thought if I can start changing it bit by bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all or nothing within a particular storyboard.  However, if you don't create any constraints in a view controller, iOS automatically generates constraints which yield the same behavior as the non-autolayout case; you can leave a view controller untouched and it will behave the same way. Then, you can manually add constraints to the view controllers you want to switch over to autolayout.

I've had luck with this so far; though, since there is automagic behind-the-scenes stuff happening, I wouldn't be surprised if there are cases which break.

Answer (score 0):

You enable autolayout on a .storyboard / .xib basis.  If you have everything in a single .storyboard, you would have to enable autolayout for the entire thing.  You could add constraints ton only some view controllers after you enable it but the other ones might look messed up on different device screen sizes.

Comment: Cannot understand why Apple, whose objective is to make developers use the newest APIs, did not made possible to enable autolayout for each view controllers - or view. Converting an entire storyboard is not only adding constraints in all interfaces, but also and mostly modifying code which writes into `UIView`s `frame`s.